# JQGrid Date Picker error

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I use the below code for show the datepicker for a text field. The grid working well. When i click the add button the 'undefined' error appear. Please help me to solve this.

```
{ name: 'FLD_PURCH_DATE', index: 'FLD_PURCH_DATE', width: 130, editable: true, edittype: "text", editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 2, elmprefix: "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='required'></span>&nbsp;" },
                            editoptions: { dataInit: function (element) { try { $(elem).datepicker(); // Error Here. } catch (ex) { alert(ex.Message);} } }

                        },
```

If i add the latest jquery url means the grid disappeared.

Comment: jquery version iss conflicting.. check which verssion your grid supports

Answer (score 0):

I use this for using datepicker.

Include datepicker in my code:

```
<script src="../../jquery.ui.datepicker-pt-BR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And editoption in my column date:

> editoptions:{ size:20,  dataInit:function(el){
>   $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'}); }}